# Listing Pages With Checkboxes In a Metabox (and saving them)

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Here is what I'm basically trying to accomplish:

1. I have a custom post type called 'quotes'
2. I have a number of wordpress pages

What I am trying to do is this: each time when I create a new "QUOTES" post, I want to be able to choose on which page this quotes post is supposed to go. I've decided to do this by creating a new metabox on the "quotes" post page and listing in that metabox all the pages, with a checkbox in front of them:

[image: pages listing metabox screenshot]

All fine and well, but now I don't know how to save these checkboxes.

Here is the function I use to print the content of the metabox:

```
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $checkfield = $custom["checkfield"][0];

    // Nonce to verify intention later
    wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' ); 
    $pages = get_pages(); 

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) { ?>   
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkfield_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" value="yes" <?php if ($checkfield == 'yes') { ?> checked <?php } ?> /> <?php echo $page->post_title; ?> <br>   
    <?php 
    } 
}
```

And here is the function I use to save them:

```
//save the meta box action
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_meta_save' );

//save the meta box
function myplugin_meta_save()
{
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'checkfield', $_POST['checkfield'] );
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work - I am not sure how to save all those checkfields values.

Comment: These two Answers may help you with this issue: [1](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38247/12615) and [2](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20069/12615). And also [this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bupdate_post_meta+%2Bsave_post).

Comment: You may be interested in the Posts 2 Posts plugin (http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts) which offers a nice interface to build relationships between post types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `checkfield_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>` as name for your input fields, then trying to save `$_POST['checkfield']` which is *not* set.

You can do the same `$pages` loop on the `myplugin_meta_save()` function and then save the data for each page as separate `meta_key` input (`checkfield_1`, `checkfield_5`, etc), OR you can save all that data in a single `meta_key` which is `checkfield` in this case, and a little tweak to your code is needed to achieve that:

```
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
    // we store data as an array, we need to unserialize it
    $checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, "checkfield", true) );

    // Nonce to verify intention later
    wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' ); 

    $pages = get_pages(); 
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) { ?>
        <input id="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" type="checkbox" name="checkfield[]" value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php if ( in_array($page->ID, (array) $checkfield) ) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/> <label for="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></label> <br>
<?php 
    } 
}
//save the meta box action
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_meta_save', 10, 2 );

//save the meta box
function myplugin_meta_save($post_id, $post)
{   
    if ( isset($_POST['checkfield']) ) { // if we get new data

        update_post_meta($post_id, "checkfield", $_POST['checkfield'] );

    }
}
```

Note that `name="checkfield"` in the input field is replaced with `name="checkfield[]"` which will make data stored as an array in `$_POST['checkfield']` variable. Also the `value` attribute is changed from `yes` to `$page->ID`.

Update: Cast `checkfield` to `array`: `if ( in_array($page->ID, (array) $checkfield) )`

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution, Ahmad - but unfortunately it gives me an error: "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in ...(my file) on line 24" - that's the line right under "foreach", the <input> line!

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution Ahmad, but unfortunately this code gives me an error:

Comment: @Gabriela: I have updated the code to make sure that `checkfield` is an array. Please make sure that `name` attr has the `[]` at the end, ie `name="checkfield[]"`

Comment: DUDE you're a lifesaver!!!!! This solved the problem and has definitely taught me a lot, thank you so much!!!